# I need to run parallel functions that keep track of variables that are in a buffer.

Tags: python, class, robotics

Here's my dilemma. I've developed some code I want to modularize but I'm stuck on what should not be a difficult issue.

My code first does something like this:

```
While True:
     value = getsensorvalue()
     values = deque(maxlen=10)

     # Get the mode value of the sensor readings
     Values = np.array(list(values))
     u, indices = np.unique(Values , return_inverse=True)
     mode = u[np.argmax(np.bincount(indices))]
     print mode
```

Basically, I'm reading a sensor value continuously, I'm storing the values in a doubly linked list (import deque from collections). This is a simplified version of my program, but basically, it's returning the mode value of the queue we formed from our sensor readings.

What I want to do is create this into a class or function that can be used to read multiple sensors. So something like this:

```
While True:
    GetSensorA()
    GetSensorB()
    GetSensorC()
    GetSensorD()
```

With all of the above having different queue lengths (buffer sizes) etc.

This has to be quite simple. I'm just a scientists who's self taught in programming. Not sure but I feel as if there is some basic programming principle I'm missing here.

Comment: if the sensor interfaces support [asynchronous actions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) that would be an option but I'm not sure I'm clear on what the issue is here, you say "your program does this first" but that's an unending loop so I fail to see how it could do anything afterwards...

Comment: That last part was just some pseudo code. In reality, i'm taking the mode values of each sensor and passing it to an API. Asynchronous actions aren't possible here. It's not actually sensors either it's data feeds, but it's very analogous to sensor like input.

Comment: when I see `while True` in a pseudo code it tells me that the content of the loop is the only thing the program is doing, could you at least post pseudo code that remotely represents the flow of your program? Otherwise I don't understand at all what you are actually asking.

Comment: Sure, my apologies i should have elaborated.